# Multiple Trigger declarations/assignments in a single statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I'd like to declare a couple of Triggers and assign them to multiple tables in a *single script*.

#### Example:

```
create or replace function trigger_a()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.fetchname := new.name;
    return new;
end
$$;

create or replace function trigger_b()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.postname := new.name;
    return new;
end
$$;

create trigger trigger_a
create trigger trigger_b

before insert or update on tableFoo
for each row execute procedure trigger_a();

before insert or update on tableBar
for each row execute procedure trigger_b();

before insert or update on tableBaz
for each row execute procedure trigger_b();
```

Running the above throws a syntax error:

> syntax error at or near "create"

Comment: single statement is when you have only one semicolon. is it what you want? or you want just in one script?

Comment: @VaoTsun yup you're right - a multi-statement SQL script is what I'm after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
create or replace function trigger_a()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.fetchname := new.name;
    return new;
end
$$;

create or replace function trigger_b()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.postname := new.name;
    return new;
end
$$;

create trigger trigger_a
before insert or update on tableFoo
for each row execute procedure trigger_a();

create trigger trigger_b
before insert or update on tableBar
for each row execute procedure trigger_b();

create trigger trigger_b2
before insert or update on tableBaz
for each row execute procedure trigger_b();
```